# How to change the data type of multiple columns in pandas and delete the invalid rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset about various infrastructural parameters of multiple countries. To perform mathematical operations, I need most of the columns to be `float64`. However, during type conversion, I came across and issue, that there are some values that just can't be converted.

Here's one of the columns and the code that I used on it

`print(country_df["GDP growth rate (annual %, const. 2005 prices)"].to_string())`

The output was

```
1        2.6
2        3.8
5        3.0
8        2.4
9        3.0
10       0.1
11       2.4
12       1.0
13       0.7
14      -1.7
15       2.9
16       6.6
17       0.9
18      -3.9
19       1.5
20       1.2
21       5.2
22       0.4
23       5.2
24       4.8
26       3.1
27      -0.3
28      -3.8
30      -0.6
31       3.0
32       4.1
33      -4.1
34       1.5
35       7.0
36       5.8
37       0.9
38       0.7
39       4.8
40       6.6
41       -99
42       2.3
43       2.4
44     -20.3
45       6.9
46       3.1
47       4.8
48       1.2
49       5.5
50       3.7
51       1.6
52       4.4
53       1.7
54       4.5
55      -1.1
56       7.0
57       1.6
58       6.5
60       7.0
61       0.2
62       4.2
63       2.5
64      -7.4
65       4.8
66       1.4
67       9.6
70       3.6
71       0.2
72       1.3
73       -99
74       1.6
75       3.9
76       4.7
77       2.8
78       1.7
79       3.9
81      -0.2
82       0.3
84       -99
85       -99
86       4.1
87       4.8
88       0.1
89       3.1
90       1.7
92       3.6
93       3.1
94       4.2
95       7.6
96       4.8
97       0.4
98      -2.4
99      26.3
101      2.5
102      0.7
103      1.0
104      1.2
105      2.4
106      1.2
107      5.6
109      1.8
110      3.5
111      7.6
112      2.7
113      1.5
114      2.8
115      0.3
116    -10.2
118      1.8
119      3.5
120      3.1
121      3.0
122      5.0
123      2.8
124      7.6
125      6.2
127      -99
128      1.2
129      3.5
131      2.5
134      2.3
135      4.5
137      4.4
138      6.6
139      7.3
140      5.3
142      2.7
143      2.0
144      3.2
145      3.1
146      4.9
147      3.6
148      2.7
151      1.6
152      5.7
153      5.5
155      5.8
156      6.6
157      3.1
158      3.3
159      5.9
160      3.9
161      1.6
162    -~0.0
163      3.6
164      2.6
165     -0.7
166      3.7
167     -3.7
168      6.9
171      1.9
173      1.6
174      2.8
176      4.0
177      3.4
178      6.5
179      0.8
180      6.8
181    -20.3
182      2.0
184      3.8
185      2.3
186      3.2
187      2.7
188      1.3
190      3.2
191      4.8
192      3.5
193      4.9
194     -2.7
195      1.7
196      4.1
197      0.8
198     -5.3
199      4.2
200      2.8
201      3.8
202      4.3
203      5.5
205      3.8
206      0.2
207      0.8
208      4.0
209      6.5
212      5.4
213     -9.9
214      3.8
215      2.2
216      7.0
217      2.6
218      -99
219      1.0
220      6.8
221     -1.0
222     -6.2
223      6.7
225      -99
226    -28.1
227      2.9
228      1.1
```

As you can see in the 162th row, the value is `-~0.0`. While this is a single value and I can easily remove it, or similar values in that column, the issue is that I have 17 more columns to convert. Each one of them have problematic values like these(There are other special characters like this a well) which hinder the type conversion.

My question is, do I have to manually check all the 17 columns, or is there an easier way to automate this and drop those rows?
P.S. One of the columns had values like `...`. I had to drop those rows manually. I only want the numbers in `float` datatype.

Comment: Not sure how you expected the data, but if you have values like this, aren't you afraid they the data could be incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

This comes up all the time in cleaning data, and the solution is typically messy, with the most careful approach being specific to the flags and symbols used by the given data source.

Check out the `na_values` argument to [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) - you can specify `na_values=['...'], keep_default_na=True` to interpret ellipses as NaN, and then develop a list of characters you're comfortable stripping from the results and process them with [`df['colname'].str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html).

To see a list of all non-convertible values, you can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with the flag `errors='coerce'` to convert errors to NaN, then look for values which map to NaN in the result:

```py
df.stack()[pd.to_numeric(df.stack(), errors='coerce').isnull()].unique()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all characters except the float and the minus character with regex, then convert to float:

```
country_df["GDP growth rate (annual %, const. 2005 prices)"] = country_df["GDP growth rate (annual %, const. 2005 prices)"].str.findall('-|\d*\.?\d+|\d+').str.join('').astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Num1': {0: '0', 1: '1.0', 2: '-2', 3: '~5', 4: '-~4', 5: '12'},
 'Num2': {0: 'r4', 1: 'r5', 2: 'g6', 3: 'foo66bar', 4: 'a6a6a', 5: 'one'},
 'String': {0: 'foo',
  1: 'bar',
  2: 'String',
  3: 'qwerty',
  4: 'qwerty1',
  5: 'qwerty123'}})

print('initially...')
print(df, '\n\n')

# find everything except 0123456789.-
pattern = r'([^0-9-.])'

for col in df.columns:
    # pick your columns to check
    if col in ['Num1', 'Num2']:
        df[col+'_removed'] = df[col].str.findall(pattern).str.join('')
        
        # comment this out to check what you have from the new columns
        df[col] = df[col].str.replace(pattern, '', regex=True)
        
print(df)

initially...
  Num1      Num2     String
0    0        r4        foo
1  1.0        r5        bar
2   -2        g6     String
3   ~5  foo66bar     qwerty
4  -~4     a6a6a    qwerty1
5   12       one  qwerty123 


  Num1 Num2     String Num1_removed Num2_removed
0    0    4        foo                         r
1  1.0    5        bar                         r
2   -2    6     String                         g
3    5   66     qwerty            ~       foobar
4   -4   66    qwerty1            ~          aaa
5   12       qwerty123                       one
```

For the first run you could comment out the line in the code above...

```
df[col] = df[col].str.replace(pattern, '', regex=True)
```

...and just run a check of what's there.